# Document Template entity in Lookup field

Tags: dynamics-crm, document-template

I am trying to use a look field on my form which displays 'documenttemplate' entity's records. But since this is a system entity I'm unable to find it in the drop down menu of entities under Target Record Type.

I've looked for a PCF control for this but lookups are not yet supported by powerapps component framework.

So is there a way to show the documenttemplate data in the lookup field?